# Centre a readline statement

Tags: c#, console, console-application, center, readline

I am about to start a project and here is what I have currently for my welcome screen.

```
string[] welcome = new string[4] 
{ 
    "Welcome", 
    "Choose A Option Bellow By Inputing The Number And Clicking Enter.", 
    "1. View C:\\Windows\\ File directory", 
    "2. View Your Own Custom Directory" 
};

string userChoice;
for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        "{0," + ((Console.WindowWidth / 2) + welcome[x].Length / 2) + "}", welcome[x]);
}
```

How do I center my read line as well? so that when the user chooses their choice will also be centered?

Comment: "and clicking Enter" --> I'm curious how you will handle that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can move the cursor using `CursorLeft` and `CursorTop` properties.
So, in your case you would do something like this :

```
Console.CursorLeft = Console.WindowWidth / 2;
// maybe -1 to center the typed number correctly
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use .Write() and format as you have before.  Then, add a Readline/ReadKey after:

```
            string[] welcome = new string[4] { "Welcome", "Choose A Option Bellow By Inputing The Number And Clicking Enter.", "1. View C:\\Windows\\ File directory", "2. View Your Own Custom Directory" };
        String userChoice;
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0," + ((Console.WindowWidth / 2) + welcome[x].Length / 2) + "}", welcome[x]);
        }
        var cprompt = "Choice:";
        Console.Write(string.Format("{0," + ((Console.WindowWidth / 2) + (cprompt.Length/2)) + "}", cprompt ));
        Console.ReadLine();
```